# How can I run a spark-job from Airflow when both Spark and Airflow are installed in the same virtual environment?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, virtualenv, airflow

I am trying to run from Airflow a test ETL pyspark job on my laptop. I have installed in the same virtual environment both Spark and Airflow. Is important to mention that I can run the job from virtual environment successfully but it fails from Airflow.
From the Airflow logs I can see that the ETL task fails because it looks for the dag file in a temporary directory when trying to execute it. Here is the error: "python: can't open file '/tmp/airflowtmpd9uwr02_/spark_etl_1.py'" (entire log below).

```
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=florian
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=Example_Airflow_and_Spark
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=spark_task_etl
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-02-24T14:28:23.580164+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-02-24T14:28:23.580164+00:00
[2021-02-24 16:28:27,498] {bash.py:135} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-02-24 16:28:27,499] {bash.py:158} INFO - Running command: /home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/SPARK/spark_env/bin/spark-submit --master local spark_etl_1.py
[2021-02-24 16:28:27,503] {bash.py:169} INFO - Output:
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,273] {bash.py:173} INFO - 21/02/24 16:28:28 WARN Utils: Your hostname, florian-TUXEDO resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.107 instead (on interface wlp2s0)
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,273] {bash.py:173} INFO - 21/02/24 16:28:28 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,620] {bash.py:173} INFO - 21/02/24 16:28:28 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,833] {bash.py:173} INFO - **python: can't open file '/tmp/airflowtmpd9uwr02_/spark_etl_1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,837] {bash.py:173} INFO - log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,837] {bash.py:173} INFO - log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,837] {bash.py:173} INFO - log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,854] {bash.py:177} INFO - Command exited with return code 2
[2021-02-24 16:28:28,857] {taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

And this is the dag code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

srcDir = "/home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/Personale/SPARK/"
sparkSubmit = "/home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/Personale/SPARK/spark_env/bin/spark-submit/"


args = {
    'owner': 'florian',
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='Example_Airflow_and_Spark',
    default_args=args,
    description='Test Spark ETL job from Airflow',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),

)


change_dir = BashOperator(
    task_id='change_working_directory',
    bash_command="cd " + srcDir,
    dag=dag,
)

### [activate virtual environment]
activate_env = BashOperator(
    task_id='activate_virtual_env',
    bash_command="source /home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/SPARK/spark_env/bin/activate",
    dag=dag,
)


### [spark_job_operator_bash]
spark_submit_cmd="/home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/SPARK/spark_env/bin/spark-submit --master local spark_etl_1.py"

spark_job = BashOperator(
    task_id='spark_task_etl',
    bash_command=spark_submit_cmd,
    dag=dag,
)


### [deactivate virtual environment]
deactivate_env = BashOperator(
    task_id='deactivate_virtual_env',
    bash_command="deactivate",
    dag=dag,
)

change_dir >> activate_env >> spark_job >> deactivate_env
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DAG resides in `AIRFLOW_HOME` which I presume is your `/tmp` folder. When you execute Spark submit, Airflow looks for the Spark script in the same folder, therefore

```sh
/home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/SPARK/spark_env/bin/spark-submit --master local spark_etl_1.py
```

is equivalent to

```sh
/home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/SPARK/spark_env/bin/spark-submit --master local ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/spark_etl_1.py
```

You might want to consider submitting the absolute path of the Spark script instead of just providing the file name `spark_etl_1.py`, e.g.

```sh
/home/florian/HDD2/WORK/PROJECTS/SPARK/spark_env/bin/spark-submit --master local /path/from/root/spark_etl_1.py
```

Comment: Your solution is not working because once it executes the pyspark module, it continues to try reading files from a temporary directory.

Comment: @FlorianC Does this mean that the module is executed albeit unsuccessfully? Then that's not an issue with the solution but with the setup of your job. If within the script you're reading files from the same directory where the Spark script lives using their relative paths, then an error will arise and that is to be expected. You should try 1. changing all paths in your Spark script to absolute ones or 2. changing directory to where the Spark script lives before calling submit.

Comment: Yes, I already tried with absolute paths and was the same problem. Meanwhile, I changed the execution operator from bash to spark_submit and the job is successfully executed now.  Thank you.